# Hibernate SessionFactory getCurrentSession is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing one problem in Hibernate. Here is the code.

```
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
    trans.begin();
    Session session2 = factory.getCurrentSession();
    System.out.println(session2.isConnected());

    trans.commit();
```

And in my cfg file

```
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">false</property>
    <mapping resource="Test.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

when i run the application with above code it is giving me an Exception saying "org.hibernate.HibernateException: isConnected is not valid without active transaction"

I don't know what behavior its performing internally. Any idea's please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at the Java doc of [SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession%28%29)

> Obtains the current session. The definition of what exactly "current" means controlled by the CurrentSessionContext impl configured for use.

So your `session` and `session2` are two different sessions. So you will have to start the transaction on `session2` to access `isConnected()`.

However if you used  `getCurrentSession()` to retrieve first session then second time `getCurrentSession()` will return you the same instance.

```
Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();//Use getCurrentSession rather than openSession
Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
trans.begin();

Session session2 = factory.getCurrentSession();//Same session will be returned.

System.out.println(session2.isConnected());
trans.commit();
```